# How to create class that provides implementations of some interfaces

Tags: java

There is some interfaces in my app and I want to create singleton class, that provides implementations of them. Like so:

```
public class Singleton{
    //singleton's stuff

    private Interface1 interface1Impl;
    private Interface2 interface2Impl;

    public Interface1 getInterface1(){
        return interface1Impl;
    }

    public Interface2 getInterface2(){
        return interface2Impl;
    }
}
```

**What I'm looking for** - provide same interface implementation for each class in app. With this way everything works fine, but is it a good way to achieve this?

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is Abstract Factory pattern.

Comment: It kind of looks like a Facade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks much like a Factory (or *maybe* Service Locator is more suitable in your case).

Factory is almost always a better idea than a Singleton. For instance, a Factory can work as a Singleton when you need it (lazy initialization, caching), and you can alter this behavior when you need something else (for testing, thread safety, etc).

Comment: Thanks, Factory is exactly what I'm looking for. But I have question - should factory's methods always create new instance of implementations, or they (implementations) can be created in constructor?

Comment: A factory method can return reusable (cached) objects: something like `Integer.fromString('1')` will return the same `Integer(1)` object for multiple invocations. You can abstract out even further and use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) as @Peter suggests. Factory moves construction of instances outside of your code. DI moves the factory outside of your code. Each interested class receives an `Interface1` implementation e.g. at creation time; the construction of this instance and control of its lifetime is on the DI framework.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you could be implementing [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), if that's the case [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) is a great library for you to use.